# Object instantiation with scope operator

Tags: c++, object, instantiation

I came across a code that is like:

```cpp
SampleObject<int>* example = new SampleObject<int>::aMethod();
```

Couldn't wrap my head around it, I'm not familiar with c++.

Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: C++ is one of the most complex computer languages out there -- there is no cheat sheet someone can just pull out and write up an answer.  It would be better to just take the time to learn the language from a good book.

Comment: This code probably needs a bit more context. A single statement by itself can mean a whole lot of different things depending on the types involved.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> SampleObject<int>* example = new SampleObject<int>::aMethod();
> ```

This can only be well-formed if `aMethod` is a member type alias of `SampleObject` that names `SampleObject` or another type whose pointer is convertible through inheritance. For example like this:

```
template<class T>
struct SampleObject{
    using aMethod = SampleObject;
};
```

> Can someone explain it to me?

It doesn't make much sense; at least not without context.

Comment: Thanks, this is kinda my homework, I didn't want to cheat. The block you wrote was left blank for me to complete it. So other than that, I don't know how to add more context to this question. But rest of the code uses example objects methods after that operation.

Comment: @brk If you copied it correctly, then frankly, it seems like a very silly homework task.

Comment: This can help a little more, inside of aMethod() is like this;

template <typename T>
...::aMethod(){
if  (instance == 0){
...
}
return instance;
}

Comment: @brk With that definition of `aMethod` as a method (as the name also suggests), the line with `new` in your question is ill-formed. Seems that the exercise is broken.